# What causes the Azure API Management time-out between request received and backend execution

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions

I have an Azure API Management resource (P2V2 tier) using Azure Functions running on a App Service Plan (P2V2 to avoid cold-starts).
One of the services calling my API is having a 1 second limit before it cancels the call.

When I trace the errors in APIM's logs for these canceled calls, I can see that we sometime receive the request, but do not trigger the Azure Function, i.e. the "backend" of the API, until up to 300-600ms later after receiving it (see image). This sometime triggers a chain reaction causing the call to exceed 1 second in total execution time.

Normal backend execution times varies between 30-60ms but there are outliers.

What is causing this delay and can I do something about it?
Can it got something to do with the number of instances (scale out) of the Function running reaching a max, and if so how can I know if I need to scale out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the problem of the function wasn't triggered in time, please check if you have enabled "**Always on**" button of your function app.

[image]

And for the question about scale out instances which you mentioned in your question, you can consider using azure function [premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal) instead of app service plan. You can configure a certain number of "[Always ready instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#always-ready-instances)" to avoid cold start and configure the "**Maximum Burst**" instances. After that, when it requires more instances, it will scale out automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Always on is on already but I will definitely check out the Premium Plan. As I understood it it also scaled out during a App Service Plan but maybe I was misstaken and that only happens when you scale out the ASP itself?

Comment: We went live with a test where we are running a Premium Function setup behind APIM instead of running them on our dedicated ASP. Unfortunately I see slightly longer avg response times from APIM. I need to evaluate how the caller experience it before I can say though. Do I need to add some other load balancer or gateway to the mix that is not solved by APIM?

Comment: Hi @RKrogh I'm not sure. But as a suggestion, could you please check if the APIM and function are in same region on Azure.

Comment: They are all in the same region. We tried changing the endpoints to http-based instead of function-based. Not sure why this would help but we seem to get somewhat less occurrences of the delays this way. Premium functions gave us a higher avg execution time but also somewhat less delays, but now we run them on the "old" ASP again. Any idea why http-based would make a difference?

Comment: Hi @RKrogh What do you mean about http-based ? Do you mean you deploy the backend api in an app which deployed on azure app service instead of on function app ?

Comment: Exactly. I cannot imagine why this would make any difference yet we see less delays this way. Maybe it is just pure luck that we see less occurrences right now though..